# Sending API calls using React JS, Redux, and Redux Logic

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-logic

I'm a quite beginner to React and Redux..I want to verify that, in developing React and Redux based applications along with redux-logic, it's not essential to have a separate backend to handle the API calls yeah?? Is it because we already have NodeJS installed in it and it acts as the backend? or Is it because of the concept of Single Page Applications?

Comment: If you're making API calls, they need to be made to something, and that something will probably be a separate backend. Really the question should be about if you need a backend at all.

Answer (score 0):

To work with React-Redux you don't need to have a separate backend.
Redux is a state management tool. With Redux, the state of your application is kept in a store and each component can access any state that it needs from this store.

I would suggest you to go through the below document to understand how react-redux works together.

https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react

https://blog.logrocket.com/why-use-redux-reasons-with-clear-examples-d21bffd5835/